# extremely slow connection to mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using a very simple connection to a localhost database:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://usr:pwd@localhost/db')
engine = engine.connect()
data = engine.execute('select * from table')
```

'table' has 500 lines. Then I run the cProfiler on 'data', where I find this:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
54086  127.261    0.002  127.261    0.002 {method 'recv' of '_socket.socket' objects}
```

here http://bugs.python.org/issue3766 it seems that it would be solved setting TCP_NODELAY to 1. My question is, where do I set this?

Comment: Why did you post to CodeReview? It seems more a StackOverflow question as you are not asking for comments on design or implementation.

Comment: ok sorry, I thought there could be something in the module that handles the connection to the database. I'll post it in stackoverflow. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `engine.setsockopt(SOL_TCP,TCP_NODELAY,1)` but not really sure.